# Creating filters for auto_html

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I want to create a custom filter for auto_html. Where do I put the filter so I can use it?
The documentation doesn't touch on any of that. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The approach I took was to add the code to an initializer file such as:

**/path/to/your/application/config/initializers/auto_html.rb**

Then you can just write something like:

```
AutoHtml.add_filter(:change_colours).with({}) do |text, options|
  text.gsub("#FF0000", "#00FF00")
end
```

And call `auto_html(input) { change_colours }` in your model. The empty hash will take any options you care to pass to the filter.