# good tutorial on how to use auto_html filters for rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I know it's supposed to be easy, but I just can't figure out how to modify an existing auto_html filter to get the output I need.  I found this     [Creating filters for auto_html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10909172/creating-filters-for-auto-html)
but I need to modify an existing filter.

for example, I have a list of youtube links in the db in this format (http://youtu.be/UfQC1h-EANI) and printed out in my view:

```
%li
  = link_to link.title, link.url, :class => "youtube title_link"
```

When the the link is clicked, I need the http://youtu.be/UfQC1h-EANI converted to http://www.youtube.com/embed/UfQC1h-EANI?rel=0

I've managed to get a conversion working using auto_html, however, it's coming with all of the html attached to it.  I'm thinking if I can modify the filter, I can adjust it to just give me the url without all the html.  I can't for the life of me figure out how to modify auto_html's youtube filter. Is this even the best approach for this?

Any help is muchly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do it with regex

```
link_to link.title, "http://youtube.com/embed/#{link.url.to_s.match(/\/\/youtu.be\/(\S+)$/)[1]}/?rel=0", :class => "youtube title_link"
```

If you want it `onclick` only, you can do it in JavaScript.